# Intercept and modify SQS SendMessageRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm using `Java AWS SDK v1` to send messages to a SQS Queue, and I want to intercept this event to add some `MessageAttributes` in the message.

I created a new RequestHandler class that extend the [RequestHandler2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/handlers/RequestHandler2.html) from the SDK to modify it before the request:

```
class CustomMessagesAttributesRequestHandler : RequestHandler2() {

    override fun beforeRequest(request: Request<*>) {
        val originalRequest = request.originalRequestObject

        if (originalRequest is SendMessageRequest) {
            originalRequest.messageAttributes["my-custom-attribute"] =
                MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("123456789")
        }
    }
}
```

The solution above kinda works, it's called `before` the request, the Message Attribute is added in the `originalRequestObject`, but when the SQS client send the request it throws an exception:

> Unable to calculate the MD5 hash of the message attributes

Digging into AWS SDK code, I see there is a default handler to check the message request with the result to compare both body and attributes MD5, and of course, since I modified the original object they does not match.

Is there a better way to achieve that besides the custom RequestHandler? Or there is a way to recalculate the originalRequestObject MD5?

Comment: Why make it this implicit and hidden? Instead just add a custom SqsMessageSender class or something and only use that class to send messages. Every other class that wants to sent messages does not use any default client but that SqsMessageSender. And in that SqsMessageSender do the custom enrichment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a data type to your message attribute value

```
new MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("some val").withDataType("String");
```

However, you might then get

```
MD5 returned by SQS does not match the calculation on the original request. (MD5 calculated by the message attributes: "fa580d7c3a1319d02f0667ae2a11f462", MD5 checksum returned: "null")
```

It would be best in your case to override the `beforeMarshalling` method.